# Failure to send an email in a contact form using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am very close to finishing this little project and all I need to do is make my contact form send emails. Easy Right? No. lol

I have got the contact form to close after a message is submitted but does not send the email and was wondering if anyone could help me with this? My code is below:

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/contact.php
http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/

Jquery:
        var doSubmit = function (event) {
          var postData = jQuery('#submit_message').serialize();

```
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/dev/contact.php',
        data: postData
      }).done(function( html ) {
        alert(html);
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    };

        $(function () {
        $('#submit_message').submit(doSubmit);
    });
```

PHP:

```
        <?php
        $your_email = "maxlynn@madaxedesign.co.uk";
        $subject = "Email From Madaxe";
        $empty_fields_message = "<p>Please go back and complete all the fields in the form.</p>";
        $thankyou_message = "<p>Thank you. Your message has been sent. We Will reply as soon as possible.</p>";

        $name = stripslashes($_POST['txtName']);
        $email = stripslashes($_POST['txtEmail']);
        $message = stripslashes($_POST['txtMessage']);

        if (!isset($_POST['txtName'])) {

        ?>

        <form id="submit_message" class="hide_900">
            <div id="NameEmail"> 
                <div>
                    <label for="txtName">Name*</label> 
                    <input type="text" title="Enter your name" name="txtName" />
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <label for="txtEmail">Email*</label> 
                    <input  type="text" title="Enter your email address" name="txtEmail" />
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div id="MessageSubmit">
                <div> 
                    <textarea maxlength="1200" title="Enter your message" name="txtMessage"></textarea> 
                    <label for="txtMessage">Message</label>
                </div>
                <div class="submit"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </form> 
        <?php

        }

        elseif (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)) {

        echo $empty_fields_message;

        }

        else {

            $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            $this_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        if ($referer != $this_url) {
        echo "You do not have permission to use this script from another URL, nice hacking attempt ;p.";
        exit;
            }

        mail($your_email, $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email>");

        echo $thankyou_message;

            }

        ?>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used new PHP and took out my own Jquery and now have to figure out a way to redirect a thank you message in my pop up. 
Thanks for your help Sam

Comment: Managed to redirect the thank you to a html file but need to make it so onclick the file pops up in the popup. Think I just use the same Jquery I have for the others

Answer (score 1):

You should debug your code to see if there is any error or bug and then include the error in your question to get a better help. But anyway, by a quick look you've got one semicolon missing in your jQuery:

```
       jQuery.ajax({
           url: '/contact.php',
           data: postData
       }).done(function (html) {
           alert(html);
       });
       event.preventDefault();
   }; // <-- HERE
```

And your HTML is malformed:

```
<div class="submit"> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label> <!-- HERE the `label` -->
</div>
```

Check these two and report back. I'm afraid that it won't fix your problem but it's worth trying.

**Update:**

Add this to your jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST", // THIS
      url: '/contact.php',
      data: postData
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, thanks for pointing that out, I've made those changes but still lye with the same problem. Thanks for your help and if you could help me even more by taking a closer look I would be very greatful.

Comment: @MaximusRobertKenwayLynn, I have updated my answer. Check and report back.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look more into this. I have updated the Jquery to what you have said and hasn't made a difference I'm afraid. I have been thinking that I may just make a contact form just using Jquery and remove the php functionality. Do not know if this is possible but think it would solve my problem. However I would prefer to work with the code that I already have, if anyone can think of any other reasons it may not send?? Thanks again

Comment: @MaximusRobertKenwayLynn, I tested the code and it was working for me. No email actually but it did print the Thank You message.

Comment: Really? Ah I wonder why it isn't doing it for me. I have updated the dev environment with your code. Is there anything I'm missing?http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/

Comment: I've noticed the URL is wrong and have changed it to http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/contact.php so it actually reads the php but still isn't working properly.

Comment: @MaximusRobertKenwayLynn, Where is your jQuery script on your page? I couldn't find the relevant `<script>` tag.

Comment: My Jquery is in the bundle but I have attached the code below. Thanks for your patients.
I've edited the question with the latest jquery

Comment: @MaximusRobertKenwayLynn, your URL `/dev/contact.php` has not been updated on your live site. Would you update it? I'm gonna try something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29301/discussion-between-maximus-robert-kenway-lynn-and-sam-rad)

Comment: @MaximusRobertKenwayLynn, join the chat